# Subfields of a splitting field using Galois correspondence

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

My question concerns the techniques for finding the subfields of a given splitting field using Galois correspondence. I still struggle sometimes with these kind of problems and thus shall ask this question applied to a concrete example.

Given the irreducible polynomial $f = X^4 + 4X^2 + 9$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, we can denote its roots by

$a = \sqrt{-2 + \sqrt{-5}}$

$b = -\sqrt{-2 + \sqrt{-5}}$

$c = \sqrt{-2 - \sqrt{-5}}$

$d = -\sqrt{-2 - \sqrt{-5}}$.

The splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is given by $L = \mathbb{Q}(a,b,c,d) = \mathbb{Q}(a)$.

The elements of the Galois-group are exactly the $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms of L, and thus are determined by the image of $a$. If we define

$\phi_1 = Id$

$\phi_2: a \mapsto b$

$\phi_3: a \mapsto c$

$\phi_4 = \phi_2 \circ \phi_3: a \mapsto d$

Results in Galois theory yield that the Galois-group of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is the Klein four-group $V_4$, which is isomorphic to the direct product of 2$\mathbb{Z}$ with itself.

Using Galois-correspondence, one can determine the subgroups of $L$. Obviously, the (non-trivial) subgroups of $G = Gal(f/\mathbb{Q})$ are $H_2 = \left\{Id, \phi_2\right\}$, $H_3 = \left\{Id, \phi_3\right\}$ and $H_4 = \left\{Id, \phi_4\right\}$.

**What follows is my attempt to find the corresponding subfields of L.**

The non-trivial subfield of $L$ corresponding to $H_2$ is given by $\mathbb{Q}(a^2)$.  This can be seen by the fact that $\phi_2(a^2) = a^2$. Now, in the same manner one could argue that it can be easily seen that $\mathbb{Q}(a + c)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(b + c)$ are the other subfields of $L$, corresponding with $H_3$ and $H_4$ respectively.

Is there a more general way to determine these subfields? One strategy that sometimes seems to work (but not in this particular example), is to determine the $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of L. This basis is equal to $\left\{1, a, a^2, a^3\right\}$. Then, one can see that $\phi_2(v + wa + xa^2 + ya^3) = v - wa + xa^2 - ya^3$  for $v, w, x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$ and thus $\phi_2(a^2) = a^2$, making $\mathbb{Q}(a^2)$ the subfield of $L$ corresponding with $H_2$. If I try the same approach for $\phi_3$ for example, I don't get anything useable. So really my question is, when does this approach work, when doesn't it, is there any more general approach to these kinds of problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of finding the subfields of a finite Galois extension is settled elegantly by the normal basis theorem. The normal basis theorem says that *every* finite Galois extension $ L/K $ admits a normal basis, that is, a basis of the $ K $-vector space $ L $ consisting of some $ \beta \in L $ and its $ K $-conjugates. If you can find such a basis, one can use a technique analogous to the *Gaussian periods* in cyclotomic field theory, which is actually a special case of the normal basis theorem.

To find a normal basis for this extension, let $ x = \sqrt{-2 + \sqrt{-5}} $, then $ \{1, x, x^2, x^3\} $ is a basis. Let $ \gamma = c_1 + c_2 x + c_3 x^2 + c_4 x^3 $ be an element. Recalling that $ 1/x = -(x^3 + 4x)/9 $, we write down the conjugates of $ \gamma $:

$$ \gamma_1 = \gamma = (c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4) $$
$$ \gamma_2 = (c_1, -c_2, c_3, -c_4) $$
$$ \gamma_3 = \left(c_1 + \frac{4c_3}{9}, \frac{4c_2}{3} + \frac{25c_4}{81}, \frac{c_3}{9}, \frac{c_2}{3} + \frac{4c_4}{81} \right) $$
$$ \gamma_4 = \left(c_1 + \frac{4c_3}{9}, -\frac{4c_2}{3} - \frac{25c_4}{81}, \frac{c_3}{9}, -\frac{c_2}{3} - \frac{4c_4}{81} \right) $$

We wish to find $ (c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4) $ such that the $ 4 \times 4 $ matrix with rows $ \gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3, \gamma_4 $ is invertible. The normal basis theorem guarantees their existence, and simple row reduction gives that this matrix is row equivalent to

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 2c_1 + c_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & c_2 & 0 & c_4 \\ c_1 + 4c_3/9 & 0 & c_3/9 & 0 \\ 0 & 4c_2/3 + 25c_4/81 & 0 & c_2/3 + 4c_4/81 \end{bmatrix} $$

We want this matrix to be invertible. We may obviously take $ c_1 = c_4 = 0 $ and $ c_3 = c_2 = 1 $, and thus, it follows that we may take

$$ \gamma = x + x^2 $$

as a generator for our normal basis. (Many different elements will work, we only need one.) Now, the primitive elements for the three subfields are found by taking the sum

$$ \sum_{\sigma \in H} \sigma(\gamma) $$

where $ H $ is the stabilizer of the subfield in the Galois group. Concretely, we have the following subfields:

$$ \mathbf Q, \mathbf Q(x^2), \mathbf Q(x^3 + x), \mathbf Q(x^3 + 7x), \mathbf Q(x + x^2) = \mathbf Q(x) = L $$

**Note:** In this particular case, we could avoid all of the work by noting that

$$ (\sqrt{-10} + \sqrt{2})^2 = -8 + 2\sqrt{-20} = 4(-2 + \sqrt{-5}) $$

and thus our mystery field $ \mathbf Q(x) $ is actually $ \mathbf Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{-10}) $. However, since the question asked for a general method, I performed the somewhat tedious computation above in order to illustrate the power of this method.

Answer (score 2):

"If I try the same approach for $\phi_3$ for example, I don't get anything useable."

Sure you do – you just have to see how to use it.

$\phi_3(a)=c$, but $ac=3$, so $\phi_3(a)=3a^{-1}$.

Now $a^4+4a^2+9=0$, so $a(a^3+4a)=-9$, so $3a^{-1}=-(1/3)(a^3+4a)$.

$\phi_3(a^2)=c^2=-2-\sqrt{-5}=-a^2-4$.

I'll let you work out $\phi_3(a^3)$ in terms of $1,a,a^2,a^3$. Then you can work out $\phi_3(v+wa+xa^2+ya^3)$, and take it from there.

Another method that often works is this: given any subgroup $H$, and any field element $r$, the element $s=\sum_{\sigma\in H}\sigma(r)$ will be in the fixed field of $H$. If you are unlucky in your choice of $r$, then $s$ might turn out to be in $\bf Q$, but then you just try to find a more clever choice of $r$.

Comment: @Star, I think you are overstating the case. The question starts out, "My question concerns the techniques for finding the subfields" and I have illustrated two such techniques. Also, OP presents a technique, and asks, "when does this approach work?" and I show that it works in the case OP brings up, you just have to push it a little harder than OP did. The methods I sketch are useful in practice. They may not get you everything, but they will get you through an introductory course in Galois Theory.

Comment: The above was in response to a comment Starfall has since deleted.